# Filter by color with exposed filters

Tags: views

I have taxonomy list of color names(red, black, etc). If I create an exposed filter form, how can I show the color with corresponding coloring? I want to style each select option with background color, i.e for the option Red, the background should be red. Can we style that in the stylesheet?

I use view3 and views_hacks
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is not necessarily Drupal related (although there is the Color module which also shows a color value in a select list, you could look into using the Color module to use its select widget or colorpicker instead of a taxonomy listing of colors by English name).

Anyways, if you want to stick with using a taxonomy select with like "blue" being the 3rd option in the select list -- you could reference this [StackOverflow example using Jquery to style select items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677350/html-dropdown-list-item-baground-colors). You could make a call to `drupal_add_js()` in a theme function whenever your view and its filters are shown on the page to add the necessary jquery.

I would recommend looking into the [Color module](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!color!color.module/7) in the long run.